# Division without Comparisons?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, binary-operations

What methods exist to divide two numbers that do not require comparison?  I am particularly interested in the case where $n$ and $d$ are integers, and we want to find $q$ such that $n=qd+r$.

I have found a number of methods that *do* use comparisons, such as:

- **Division by repeated subtraction**
  Subtract $d$ from $n$ until $n<0$, which clearly uses a comparison.
- **Egyption Division**
  We try to guess the quotients binary decomposition by multiplying $d$ by powers of 2 and comparing if they are bigger or less than $n$.

The methods I have found that do satisfy my the no-comparison rule are:

- **Goldschmidt Division** which uses the following recurrence relation to approximate division
  $a_{i+1} = a_i * r_i \quad a_0 = n \\ b_{i+1} = b_i * r_i \quad b_0 = d \\ r_{i+1} = 2 - b_i \quad r_0 \in (0, 1)$
- **Newton-Raphson Division** which also uses a recurrence relation to compute
  $q = x_k$ where $k ≥ \left \lceil \log_2(log_{17} (n + 1)) \right \rceil$ and
  $x_{i+1} = 2x_i - dx_i^2$ with $x_0 \in (0, 1)$

What other division methods are there that don't rely on comparisons? and Are there any such methods that do not use approximation like the two above?

[Another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55180/is-there-a-non-guessing-way-to-do-a-simple-division-operation) asks about similar methods that don't "guess" $q$, but the answers there don't fit my criteria of minimal comparisons.  Also, please correct me if I made any mistakes in describing the methods above.

Comment: The specific reason I ask is because I'm working with a system where addition, subtraction and multiplications are super fast, but bitwise operations and comparisons are painfully slow.  I'm hoping there is a way to do $\lfloor a/b \rfloor$ efficiently in this environment.

Comment: You're interested in methods that work with integers, but can they use intermediate floating point representations, or should they strictly stick to integers? I haven't yet checked the two methods you mentionned in details, but those look like they're intended for floating point numbers.

Comment: @n-bach Only integers.  The reason I ask for methods other than Goldschmidt and Newton's method is because to simulate fractions in an integer environment, we have to do division anyway, eg. 0.50*0.50 = 50*50/10000.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point. Fractions (rational numbers?) are not the same as floating point numbers. Summarizing [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), you can encode non-integers numbers of the form $a\times 2^b$ by storing $a$ and $b$ in memory, where $a$ and $b$ are of course constrained to be (possibly $<0$) integers. Assuming you can perform integer addition/substraction/multiplication + bitwise operations, you can also perform addition/substraction/multiplication on these so-called floating point numbers. What can be more tricky, is computing the decimal expansion.

Comment: One reason I asked about floating point numbers, is that some environments may not have good support for floats, and using them results in slower performances (assuming you have alternatives).